# Android Package Manager List Doesn't Show Navigation Icon

Tags: java, android

I'm using the below code to get a list of applications:

```
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    Collections.sort(packages, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));
    for (int i = 0; i < packages.size(); i++) {
        if (packages.get(i).uid > 10000) {
            try {
                Log.d(pm.getApplicationLabel(packages.get(i));
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the issue is that there are some applications that don't show in the list, such as Google Navigation. Any idea why this is?

Comment: perhaps those applications have a UID <= 10000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using that worked perfectly:

```
Intent applications = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
applications.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
applicationIntentList = pm.queryIntentActivities(applications, 0);
```